# C++ Multithreaded debug macro

Tags: c++, multithreading, macros

I am trying to write simple debug macro that will work with multiple threads running it. I must be obviously missing something, because the std::cout output is not synchronized. Any help much appreciated.

```
//=======Debugger========//

#ifndef _DEBUGGER_H_
#define _DEBUGGER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

/*
 * Debugger. All messages are directed to std::cout
 */

#ifndef WITH_NOCOLOR
 #define COLOR_GREEN        "\e[0;32m"
 #define COLOR_RED          "\e[1;91m"
 #define COLOR_CYAN         "\e[1;36m"
 #define COLOR_YELLOW       "\e[1;33m"
 #define COLOR_ORANGE       "\e[0;33m"
 #define RESET_COLOR        "\e[m"
#else
 #define COLOR_GREEN        ""
 #define COLOR_RED          ""
 #define COLOR_CYAN         ""
 #define COLOR_YELLOW       ""
 #define COLOR_ORANGE       ""
 #define RESET_COLOR        ""
#endif //WITH_NOCOLOR

#define THREAD_ID           "[thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] "
#define THREAD_SYNC_START   { std::lock_guard< std::mutex > lock( sync_mutex );
#define THREAD_SYNC_STOP    }

static std::mutex sync_mutex;

#define DEBUG       "[Debug]: "
#define ERROR       "[Error]: "
#define INFO        "[Info ]: "
#define WARNING     "[Warn ]: "

#define Debug(x)    do { THREAD_SYNC_START \
                    std::cout << COLOR_CYAN << DEBUG << RESET_COLOR <<  THREAD_ID << x << std::endl; \
                    THREAD_SYNC_STOP \
                    }while(0)

#define Err(x)      do { THREAD_SYNC_START \
                    std::cout << COLOR_RED << ERROR << COLOR_ORANGE << THREAD_ID << x << RESET_COLOR << std::endl; \
                    THREAD_SYNC_STOP \
                    }while(0)

#define Info(x)     do { THREAD_SYNC_START \
                    std::cout << INFO << THREAD_ID << x <<std::endl; \
                    THREAD_SYNC_STOP \
                    }while(0)

#define Warn(x)     do { THREAD_SYNC_START \
                    std::cout << COLOR_YELLOW << WARNING << RESET_COLOR << THREAD_ID << x << std::endl; \
                    THREAD_SYNC_STOP \
                    }while(0);

#endif //_DEBUGGER_H_
```

Output:

> [Debug]: [thread: [Debug]: [thread: 1074275136] Starting Log..1099953248]  init start

Comment: @Amartel That's included implicitly in `std::endl`. (and, thus, the primary reason why using `std::endl` instead of `'\n'` can kill performance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youre `sync_mutex` is a `static` namespace-scope variable, which means that it has internal linkage—each translation unit (`.cpp` file) which includes the header will have its own copy of the mutex. Accesses from different translation units are therefore not synchronised.

You need to make sure there's only one `sync_mutex` object for the entire program. The most obvious way would be to turn the mutex into an `extern` variable instead of a `static` one, and then define it in exactly one source file.

Alternatively, if you wanted to stay header-only, you could have it be a static local variable inside an inline function:

```
#define THREAD_SYNC_START   { std::lock_guard< std::mutex > lock( sync_mutex() );

inline std::mutex& sync_mutex()
{
  static std::mutex m;
  return m;
}
```